# Manually connect to Rails DB from mailman app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailman-gem

I am using mailman for receiving of emails and I need to put received emails to DB. As long as mailman is a separate app, I can not use ActivRecord directly. Could you advice how manually to connect to Rails DB without ActivRecord.